# Rooting Micromax A87 to make it faster

Tags: rooting, ram, micromax-a87

What is the best way to root my Micromax A87?

My phone RAM shows only 160MB, but I only access about 120MB.
I want my phone to run faster.

Or is there any common method for rooting my phone.
Kindly help me.

Comment: Just by rooting you will not make your phone run faster. You may have to do a lot like throttle CPU speed, manage memory etc to achieve it. Of course, for all these you have to root your phone.

Comment: I added a link to your question on our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). You might want to have a look over there, maybe one of the described "general methods" applies to your device. If you succeeded, don't forget to update that fact here -- you might even answer your own question, describing the steps involved, if nobody else did that here ;)

Comment: Just realized now that Micromax devices are already rooted! Yep, this is true at least for Micromax Funbook Tablet and Micromax A110 phone. Install and run [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qb2V5a3JpbS5yb290Y2hlY2siXQ..) which will reveal whether your device is already rooted.

Comment: @Narayanan I have checked but my Micromax A87 not rooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1896665) thread speaks about rooting MicroMax A87 Ninja which seems to be quite easy and broken into following easy steps:

1. Preparation of computer which includes downloading JDK, SDK, ADB driver and One click tool to root.
2. Connect the phone and run the root tool.

I am skipping on rest of the details as the XDA thread enumerates its details.